# How to find a file in the project file tree in Brackets

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-brackets

I'm wondering if there is a way (either built in or by using an extension) to find a file (not a string in a file) in the file tree of the project in Brackets.
This is so if I have many folders and files, I don't have to look for the file manually. Hopefully when the file is found, it will be shown and/or be highlighted in the file tree as well.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried the **Quick Open** shortcut? It's an instant file search that lets you open any file in the current project. It's command is Ctrl-Shift-O

[Brackets shortcuts](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/Brackets-Shortcuts)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did not know about this and it seems to work well, but does not bring the file into the view. Nonetheless, it is very handy and for the most part does the job.